# Why is there a conversion error in this code?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, type-conversion

I'm just making a program and this happens
I don't understand where is converts like that.

This program is supposed to see how many of each character is in a input string. It is work in progress but I already made a for loop to process the input.

Error:
`11:30: error: conversion from 'int' to non-scalar type 'std::vector<int>' requested`

Code:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string input;
  vector<int> letters = (26,0);
  vector<char> alpha = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
  
    cin >> input;
    for(int i = 0; i < input.size();i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < alpha.size(); j++){
            if(input[i]==alpha[j]){
                letters[j] ++;
            }
        }
    }
  
  
}
```

Comment: This is a typo. `(26, 0)` evaluates to just `0`. You're trying to assign `vector<int> letters = 0;` You need squiggly-wiggly brackets instead of parentheses.

Comment: vector<int> test_scores_b (10,75); works on my IDE

Comment: `vector<int> test_scores_b (10,75)` calls the constructor for `std::vector<int>` that takes two integers. It's distinct from `std::vector<int> letters = (10, 75);`

Comment: oh sorry, that was why,

Comment: [Here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) are the constructor for `std::vector<T>`. It reads like, well, programming language reference documentation, but this site in particular is an invaluable help to the community.

Comment: You may need to know how debugger works. It would save you a lot of time debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is that you try to call constructor with 2 parameters, using assign without explicitly showing  what are that 2 ints mean. You can choose 2 ways of this implementation:

```
vector<int> letters = vector<int>(26, 0);//here you call copy constructor

vector<int> letters(26,0); // here you call constructor with 2 parameters
```

Compiler just don't know what do you mean writing "vector letters = (26,0);" it's could be everything - from just 1 int number to implicit convertion to your classes; So you should to show it explicitly.